# Question about Improper Integral of Product

Tags: calculus

I'm given with the following data:
$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx $ is finite 
, g(x) is a bounded and continous function at $(0,\infty ) $ .

Prove that $ \int_0 ^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx $ converges...

Ok. So I know that $  mf(x) \leq f(x)g(x) \leq Mf(x) $ for some constants $m,M$ . So if the integral of f(x)g(x) exists, its value must be between the integral of both sides...

But why does $f(x)g(x) $ must be integrable?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Can’t delete my old, incorrect answer because it’s been accepted....)</sub>$\newcommand{\ud}{\mathrm d}$

Per @user’s comment below, take $f(x) = g(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$.

$\int_0^\infty f(x) \,\ud x$ turns out to be $\sqrt{\pi / 2}$, which is of course finite.

$g(x)$ is bounded (you can check that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$) and continuous.

But $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, g(x) \,\ud x = \int \frac{\sin^2 x}{x} \ud x$ diverges.

If we were talking about an integral over $(a, b)$ for finite $a, b$, then the property would hold, per the proof that used to be in this answer [check the edit history]. But on infinite domains, this is not true.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I haven't learn about Riemann Measure? How can I show the product is integrable ? Thanks !!!

Comment: Consider $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}$. The integral of $f(x)$ converges that of $f(x)g(x)$ does not.

Comment: @user Indeed, looking at it now this old answer of mine was just wrong. (That condition is only good on _compact_ domains....)